# Unable to install anything, filename too short

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm fairly new to the Linux scene (installed yesterday), but have been having problems ever since. I've managed to get my touchpad working (for now), but am now unable to install anything. I have tried quite a few things, and am now able to write `sudo apt-get` fairly efficiently. Every different attempt returns with the error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64' contains empty filename
```

I have tried `sudo nautilus` and deleting everything under `/var/lib/dpkg/updates` as suggested on another answer, but still the same response. I'd really like to install some things from the software centre, I currently don't have flash (but that's a totally different matter).

Also, every time I log on, I get several error messages. I am assuming this has something to do with the matter.

I apologise for the incorrect post format, I tried doing the cool code thingy I've seen everyone else do but was unable to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try deleting the .list file in the dpkg info directory:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64.list
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I did this, but then got the same error with "libwbclient0:amd64". I then went and deleted this too (I hope it was okay to do). Now I'm getting the same error with "rsyslog". Should I continue to delete all files which respond with the same response?

Comment: Was there any problem while installation?

Comment: I don't think you'll encounter any problems if you delete them but, to be safe you can move them to another directory: `sudo mkdir ~/listsbackup` and then `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/filename.list ~/listsbackup/filename.list` (Don't forget to change `filename` to a specific file name, for example `rsyslog`. This way, if you do have any problems, you could always move them to where they were before.

Comment: @ m2k1981 , no problems during installation. However, I did try to recover some data through testdisk, as I accidentally formated the disk during the installation. I have my touchpad working now, however, so I've got that going for me.

Comment: I didn't know enter meant send :(
@ Mertcan Ekiz , I'll try that now. Have since been getting errors with thunderbird-gnome-support, so I tried to uninstall it, but it is still there. So I did it again, but still getting the error. I will continue to move the files, but I have some suspicion that this will be going on for a long time. Thanks for all the replies, all.

Comment: After a while, it worked!! After moving the files I was able to install VLC. Thanks a lot for all your help guys! Question answered.

Comment: I don't know how to select your comment as the answer, sorry.

Comment: I'm glad you could get it to work! Yeah, you can't select a comment as an answer but you can select my original answer